# How can I add an impulse to specific rigid bodies at rest?

Tags: physics, box2d, ios, cocos2d-iphone, rigid-body-dynamics

**Scenario**

Rocks falling down a rocky slope, with a flat surface at the bottom.
When they land on the surface, the rocks move slightly before coming to a rest.

`GLESDebugDraw` shows the bright orange outline turning to a slightly darker orange once a rock comes to a rest, until the rock is agitated by another falling rock.

**Question:** I would like to add an impulse to the rock once it reaches the rest state. How would I implement that?

Comment: Given that this has been edited, I'm surprised none has provided any kind of comment or answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sleeping allowed (and the [`b2_timeToSleep`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/b2_settings_8h.html#ab021adb740e4a5e1f5f7d9913ed94781) is sufficiently short for your needs) you can use the [`b2Body::isAwake`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/classb2_body.html#aa28fdb95dffac89d20b04bd1a038b4ea) function to test if a rock is settled.

Pseudo-code:

```
For body in bodies:
  If(body is rock and not body->isAwake()) Then
    //Apply impulse
  End If
End loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem before when I was developing some physics code for a college project. I'm going to make an assumption that there is some code handling whether or not your rock is in a rest state. If you don't have this piece of code then it can be implemented as follows:

```
float positionEpsilon = [EPSILONVAL] // Use to check if the position of the rock has changed by a significant amount

// Update the rock 
void UpdateRock(Time delta)
{
    changeInPosition = [CURRPOS] - [PREVPOS] // Take the last position from the current position
    .
    .     // Some code
    .
    if(changeInPosition < positionEpsilon)
    {
        // Here you could perform an action on the rock
        // or put it to sleep and check if it's asleep
        // in another part of the code
    }
}
```

That's a general enough explanation of how I got it working in my project where I just used basic C++ to build the engine. You're using Box2D so it should be much easier to check if a body is asleep using b2Body::isAwake() function.